# CountIF with OR in Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm writing a `COUNTIF` to count the number of rows between two columns where at least one of the cells in the row is not blank. The logic is as follows:

COUNTIF($A:$A OR $B:$B, "<>"&"")

I know I can't nest an `OR` within a `COUNTIF`, but is there something else I can do? I am familiar with using an array when you have multiple criteria, but I don't believe that works for ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two COUNTIF an one COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"<>")+COUNTIF(B:B,"<>")-COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>",B:B,"<>")
```

Or you need to limit the data range to use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A1000<>"")+(B1:B1000<>"")>0))
```

Comment: Easy and simple, you're on a roll!

Comment: @BigBen oh, you were referring to the last one where I over complicated it.  Yeah I tend to run down a path and sometimes it is the most hilly and rocky path, totally missing the even well worn path. Ce la vi.

Comment: Actually I totally had forgotten about that one, ha. There just have been so many questions to answer today, it's kept me from being productive elsewhere. Meant that comment more as a, "nice, you're pumping answers out today."

Comment: @BigBen Yeah but I am done for the day.  Hit the limit.  So I will back off an do some actual work.